# Subtraction of 2, 2s complent numbers

Tags: binary, subtraction

I have a problem with the subtraction of 2s complement.

I tried subtracting `(-22) - 12 = (-22) + (-12)` this is what I get:

```
-22 = 1110 1010
-12 = 1111 0100

1110 1010
+   1111 0100
= (1)1101 1110
```

If I understand it correctly, the overflow indicates that it's a negative number but `1101 1110` isn't `34` ?

I don't see where I'm wrong ...

Thanks !

Comment: it look ok. you get -34 what is the problem?

Comment: Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429784/binary-subtraction-with-2s-complement), in the best answer I saw that the result is (1)10000 which I understand is -16 (2^4). But my answer is (1)1101 1110 which is -222 (2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^6+2^7)

Comment: your answer 111011110 is
-(2^8-(2^7+2^6+2^4+2^3+2^2+2))=-34

Comment: If you have another problem with this, ask.. if not, please put  V to the answer. thanks

Comment: I get it now, Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is:

```
 111011110 = -(2^8-(2^7+2^6+2^4+2^3+2^2+2))=-34
```

you can calculate it  another way

```
  111011110  = -(000100001 +1)= -(000100010)=-34
```